# workaround or alternative to overflow-x : clip? or use sticky without having to remove overflow : hidden?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, frontend, web-frontend

I'm looking for alternative or workaround for overflow-x: clip, since it is not supported on IOS safari mobile below version 16,

I have a sticky div, while scrolling above that div sticks but it's parent to parent to parent div has overflow : hidden,

```
 HTML 
 <div className = "parent-div">
  <div> 
    <div>
      <div className="sticky-div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div>
```

so sticky does not work in that case, so I had to make it overflow : visiable so in that case user can scroll/swipe vertically and horizontally both but I don't want the horizontal swipe/scroll so I have used overflow-x : clip but it is not supported in safari below version 16

```
    .parent-div{
      overflow: visible;
      overflow-x: clip // does not support in safari below version 16
    }

    .sticky-div {
     z-index: 2;
     position: -webkit-sticky;
     position: sticky;
     top: 0px;
  }
```

Or is there any way to use position : sticky without having to remove overflow : hidden from parent or ancetor div's ?